# How to add transition effect in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

I want to add transition effect to my code. When `error` css appear it should be added transition but I could not apply it. I know how to add transition when hovering but I don't know how to this kind of situation?

**Here is my css**

```
.error{
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
   transition:all linear 0.5s;
}
```

**Html**

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='appCtrl'>
    <form name="myForm" >
  userType: <input name="input" ng-model="userType" required>
  <div class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
      <p>err</p>
  </div>

 </form>
</div>
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/8atm9bdb/1/

Comment: For a property to transition between two values, you have to change the value of the property. You don't seem to have done that.

Comment: When do you want the transition to occur? I can't seem to understand that.

Comment: I want to add transition when `class="error"` appeared is it possible?

Comment: Transitions do not work on the `display` property. You will need to show/hide the element in another way if you want a transition. `Visibility` or `opacity` should work.

Comment: @Quentin similar to this http://jsfiddle.net/8atm9bdb/3/

Comment: @APAD1 should i hide `error` class ? to add transition?

Comment: You need to alter the way the error element is being displayed. Currently it is being hidden by applying `display:none;` to the element which cannot be transitioned.

Comment: is there any ways using `::after` or `::before` elements. I've tried lots of time could you give me some examples similar to this I don't want it should be the same code any code without `:hover` effect. Please...

Comment: How would adding pseudo selectors help? You need to change the way the error element is being hidden, period. Instead of `display:none;`/`display:block;` use `opacity:0;`/`opacity:1;`

Comment: @APAD1 could you give some examples similar to this.....

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found my mistake. Most of the transition effects can be achieved by `ngAnimate`

```
.error.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
.error.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
}
```

http://www.nganimate.org/